# Why php DOMDocument savehtml break structure

Tags: php, xml, dom

I have a problem when trying to modify html content using DomDocument in PHP, so for example i have this code

```
<h1>Foo<p>bar</p></h1>
```

And then when I try to turn it back using saveHtml() method it gives me the wrong result like this

```
<h1>Foo</h1><p>bar</p>
```

I already tried to fix it but to no avail, so my question is, how do I prevent that from happening?

Thank you guys.

Comment: `p` are not allowed inside `h1`. So the starting `p` ends the previous `h1`. You can test this with the W3C validator.

Answer (score 0):

While @ThW is right, you can bypass the issue by parsing the string with an xml parser instead of an html parser - that rule doesn't apply with xml...

For example:

```
$doc = simplexml_load_string("<h1>Foo<p>bar</p></h1>");
$bars =  $doc->xpath('//p');

foreach ($bars as $bar) {
   $bar[0]="not bar";
};

$domxml = dom_import_simplexml($doc);
echo $domxml->ownerDocument->saveXML($domxml->ownerDocument->documentElement);
```

Output:

```
<h1>Foo<p>not bar</p></h1>
```